# LocationupdateEx is not giving PRIORITY_HD_ACCURACY data

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Hi I developed an app using HMS core SDK for HD Location API.
PRIORITY_HD_ACCURACY =      200;
// Precise location session Used API:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/fusedlocationproviderclient#11

I am gettinglocations, but when I checked the Source Type

int source = location.getExtras().getInt("SourceType", 0);

Source type is coming as 19 and 128 where last but three bits are not 1.

Please help me in this why locations are not from HD_ACCURACY API.

Answer (score 0):

LocationupdateEx() only use in China therefore, you cannot obtain PRIORITY_HD_ACCURACY data